# Custom .find() tied to a Sequelize Model

Tags: model, find, sequelize.js

Couldn't find what I wanted in the documentation, so I'm just going to leave this here and hope for some help!

I have a specific query that I need to run on my user Model with a lot of includes and those includes all have where statements inside of them... 
So, I'd like to unclutter my controller and put this logic

`User.findById(userId, {include: [{
        model: Model1,
        where: { aCondition: false}
    },{
        model: Model2,
        where: { aCondition: false}
    },{
        model: Model3,
        where: { aCondition: false}
    },{
        model: Model4,
        where: { aCondition: false}
    },{
        model: Model5,
        where: { aCondition: false}
    }]}).then()`

into the Model itself so I'd just be able to call

`User.findByIdWithIncludes(userId).then()`

inside of my controller.

Does this functionality exist and I'm just missing it?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of select can be done with the use of "Scopes",
http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/scopes/

By defining your models like that:

```
var Project = sequelize.define('Model1', {
  // Attributes
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    where: {
      aCondition: false
    }
  }
});
```

It will be used with every find().
You can define multiple scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models

That definitely gives you the chance to create a `findByIdWithIncludes` method on your Model

Comment: Thank you! Fixed my problem and allowed me to consolidate my logic to the model files.